# Disable Light probe icons

Tags: unity-game-engine, icons, light

[image: demo]

I've tried deactivating lights & light probe icons but this yellow lines and grey spheres keep appearing every time that i click an object.

I can hardly see the objects that im placing with that sphere overlaping them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the editor window there is a drop down menu named `Gizmos` in the top right corner. Click on it and unselect `LightProbeGroup` to hide it.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Unity should seriously consider making these icons semi-transparent, or smaller.